# Error with C# String.Replace for double quote

Tags: c#, string, replace, quote

I'm using the following to convert a string containing `&quot;` to the actual double quote symbol `"`.

```
string correctname = name.Replace("&quot;", "\"");
```

It actually returns backslash followed by double quoted: ' \" '. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: that is how its shown. `\"` is actually `"`. so dont worry

Comment: Note that you can also use `@""""` (instead of `"\""`), although it is less pretty

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's working: a double quot is shown using a escape sequence when you watch it using the debugger.

BTW, I believe you should use [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354(v=vs.110).aspx) if you're looking for decoding [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).